# control with ID 'ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_divDetailsContent' could not be found, but it's right there!

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to add a control I created dynamically, but I get this error:

The TargetControlID of 'abc' is not valid. A control with ID 'ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_divDetailsContent' could not be found.

The aspx page looks like this: (PSEUDO CODE ALERT)

```
.
.
<panel id="myPanel" runat="server" ... >
<div id="divDetailsContent" runat="server" style="width:100%">
.
.
<% this.Controls.Add(GetAnimationExtender(myPanel)); %>
.
.
```

I have tried both the ID and ClientID properties but still the error. Any ideas?

Edit:

Lots of confused answers, here is a shorter version of my method as I commented most of it out, the error is the same with just this code:

```
public static UpdatePanelAnimationExtender GetAnimationExtender(PlaceHolder loadingMessagePlaceHolder, Control targetControl, UpdatePanel targetPanel)
{

    UpdatePanelAnimationExtender ae = new UpdatePanelAnimationExtender();

    ae.ID = GenerateRandomControlID();
    ae.TargetControlID = targetPanel.ClientID;
  return ae;
}
```

It says it cannot find the TargetControlID yet it passes the panel to it

Comment: Your method takes a Placeholder, I don't think <div runat="server"> and <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server"> are interchangable even though the placeholder results in a div being rendered in the final html. I could be wrong, maybe the aspx parser is smarter than me.

Comment: Updated to make it easier to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved that particular issue... I had to use UniqueID.

Now I found that it has to be done on pre-render, argh! But that's a problem for another day...

Comment: for doing something doing pre_render you can use Page_PreRender event handler.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using runat="server" attr in any html control then you don't need to say ClientID, instead, use ID and :

```
<div id="divDetailsContent" runat="server" style="width:100%">
.
.
<% this.Controls.Add(blah.GetControl(divDetailsContent.ID)); %>
.
.
public static Control GetControl(n)
{
.
.
blah.TargetID = n;
.
.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay - The TargetControlID of 'ac61bc8320c61104' is not valid. A control with ID 'divDetailsContent' could not be found. (using .ID)

Answer (score 1):

Aaron had the right idea - your runat="server" means you don't need to sweat clientID or UniqueID.  What's the real issue here is this:

```
// You're trying to call blah.GetControl using the control name
<% this.Controls.Add(blah.GetControl(divDetailsContent.ClientID)); %>

//Yet GetControl is static ?  So what exactly is this function doing that it cannot find the control?
public static blah GetControl(n)
{
  //How is blah a method and an object?
  blah.TargetID = n;       
}
```

EDIT:
You're setting ae.TargetControlID twice - are you sure it's the correct target both times?

Additionally, do you know if you need to add it to the page prior to specifying the TargetControlID?   It might be that it needs to be loaded on the page prior to being able to find the target control.

EDIT 2:
You're setting ae.TargetControlID to the ClientID of the update panel.  This is incorrect - it needs to be the ID of the UpdatePanel.  Whether or not it can find it I'm betting will be based off of the problem I mentioned previously.

Comment: it doesnt make sense above because its pseudo-c#, but the entire method is posted above now.

Comment: Yeah that is perhaps the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear what you are trying to do. If this code is on the .aspx page, then adding

`<div id="divDetailsContent" runat="server" style="width:100%">`

to the page where you want it will automatically add it to the page. Attempting to add it again to the parent using `this.Controls.Add` would result in a second rendering of the control tree. This could lead to unintended consequences.

I think adding the div with the runat=server is enough.

Comment: Sorry, its because what I am doing is a bit complicated, which is why I am trying to write this...
I was hesitant to go into detail because its complex explaining what I want to do. What I did worked fine before, and now I am just converting it into C# code to be able to do it over and over dynamically.
It's trying to add an animation extender dynamically, add a div with "Loading" in to a placeholder, and have two update methods that point to the content div.
It just doesn't want to add the extender because it says targetcontrolID is not valid.